# eclipse won't let me access the constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

The documentation of the class's constructors:

```
Constructor Detail
GenerateNextNumberRequest

public GenerateNextNumberRequest()
Default no-arg constructor
GenerateNextNumberRequest

public GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum nextNumberType,
                             BigDecimal numberOfValues)
Required Fields Constructor
```

However, if I access the constructor like this:

```
GenerateNextNumberRequest nnRequest = new GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum.RMANUMBER, 1);
```

Eclipse displays an error and is telling me to remove the arguments in order to create an object of "GenerateNextNumberRequest".
Am I doing something wrong?
May the documentation be outdated?

Thanks :)

Comment: And is int a BigDecimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing integer as second argument to constructor and your constructor expects a BigDecimal object. Bigdecimal is not same as integer. So you may want to call your constructor as:

```
GenerateNextNumberRequest nnRequest = new GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum.RMANUMBER, BigDecimal.ONE);
```

Comment: Thanks! :) 
Exactly the solution. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument should be a BigDecimal object. You are currently passing an int. Fix this like so:

```
GenerateNextNumberRequest nnRequest = new GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum.RMANUMBER, new BigDecimal(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `1` to `new BigDecimal(1)` while instantiation or `BigDecimal numberOfValues` to `int numberOfValues` in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

1 (the second argument in the constructor) is not a BigDecimal. Please refer to the documentation. 
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of the constructor is object of class BigDecimal. However, you put literal 1, which is by default of primitive type int. That's the mismatch.

If you want to go this way, you should/could call constructor for BigDecimal(1) as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have no constructor with arguments `NextNumberTypeEnum nextNumberType, int numberOfValues`

```
GenerateNextNumberRequest nnRequest = new GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum.RMANUMBER, 1);
```

You have to change the call of constructor  to:

```
GenerateNextNumberRequest nnRequest = new GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum.RMANUMBER, BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
```

Or change your constructor to:

```
public GenerateNextNumberRequest(NextNumberTypeEnum nextNumberType,
                             int numberOfValues)
```